# TFS 2012 merge by changeset actually merges more code than the selected changeset

Tags: visual-studio-2012, merge, changeset

I want to merge a bug fix from a dev branch to a release branch with VS+TFS 2012.

I merge by selecting only the changeset corresponding to the bug fix, but then it merges another previous changeset on the same file too.

I've done this many times in the past and I don't remember had this problem, is there something I don't understand about this feature ? I thought it was precisely designed for taking only the changes of a single check-in, but it does not behave like this...

Does anybody have an explanation ?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps the code was reformatted with the changeset you are trying to merge? For instance, tabs might be changed to white-spaces and as a result VS tries to merge the whole file.

Comment: Nope i just verified, at first I thought it could be that because I'm comparing versions with ignoring blank spaces, but i did the comparaison again and it is not that.  
  
The only thing I think could explain is that the 2 changesets are modifying adjacent sections of the code and the blank line between the 2 sections seems to be shared by the 2 changesets, could that explain what happens ?   
If its that I still don't understand why tfs would take all the changes of the previous changeset too, it seems a bug to me.